# How can I check when any blog was last updated in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'd like to write a script that takes the URL of any blog and returns the date of its most recent post.

So far I have tried two ways.

The first is `htmldate`, which has a high error rate for this use case:

```
import requests
from htmldate import find_date

url = 'xxx'

# Check URL content
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    html_content = response.text
else:
    print(f"Failed to fetch HTML content. Status code: {response.status_code}")

# Use HTML content with htmldate
if response.status_code == 200:
    date = find_date(html_content, outputformat='%d %B %Y')
    print(date)
else:
    print("Skipping htmldate processing due to failed HTML content retrieval.")
```

The second is `BeautifulSoup`, but it relies on providing a comprehensive list of possible tags for the date:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dateutil import parser

def get_latest_post_date(url):
    try:
        # Send HTTP GET request to blog URL
        response = requests.get(url)

        # Check if request was successful
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Parse HTML content of page
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

            # List of common HTML elements that might contain publication date
            date_elements = [
                soup.find('time'),
                soup.find('span', class_='date'),
                soup.find('span', class_='post-date'),
                soup.find('span', class_='dated-posted'),
                soup.find('div', class_='post-date'),
                soup.find('span', {'itemprop': 'datePublished'}),
                soup.find('meta', {'itemprop': 'datePublished'}),
                soup.find('span', {'property': 'article:published_time'}),
                soup.find('meta', {'property': 'article:published_time'}),
                # Add more elements based on the structure of the specific blog
            ]

            # Find first non-empty date element
            date_element = next((element for element in date_elements if element and element.text.strip()), None)

            if date_element:
                # Extract date string and parse into datetime object
                date_string = date_element.text.strip()
                date = parser.parse(date_string)
                return date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # Format the date as needed
            else:
                return "Date not found on the page"

        else:
            return f"Failed to retrieve the page. Status code: {response.status_code}"

    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: {e}"

blog_url = 'xxx'
latest_post_date = get_latest_post_date(blog_url)

print(f"The date of the latest post on {blog_url} is: {latest_post_date}")
```

Is there another method that could do this more successfully?

Comment: I don't see a way where you don't have to do a variation of your second script. "Time of last update" is not a standard feature in blog engines. And some blogs don't use an engine at all.

Comment: To check when a blog was last updated using Python, you can make an HTTP request to the blog's URL and inspect the HTTP headers or the HTML content for a last-modified date. However, this part is highly specific to the structure of the blog's HTML...